# AdMob bannerview changing position

Tags: admob, unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity2d game in which I have been asked to put admob bannerview. I read the tutorial and everything put in place. Now the difficult part is, I want to change the existing bannerview position from top to bottom when I navigate from Home page to GamePlay screen without destroying and recreating ta new bannerview object.

```
     #if UNITY_ANDROID
     string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
     #elif UNITY_IPHONE
     string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
     #else
     string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
     #endif

     // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
     BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);
     // Create an empty ad request.
     AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
     // Load the banner with the request.
     bannerView.LoadAd(request);
```

I can shift bannerview position by calling bannerView.Hide() and Destroy() and creating a brand new bannerView. Doing so, creating unnecessary lag in loading new Request.

```
    bannerView.Hide (); 
    bannerView.Destroy();
```

I want to eliminate this delay by shifting existing bannerview position,

But I couldn't find any method in bannerview class to shift x/y position.

Comment: there is no such method available in unity admob sdk to shift existing bannerview position. Destroying and recreating a new bannerview instance is your only hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to destroy and create a new bannerview instance by setting AdPosition.Bottom or AdPosition.Top.
As of now, there is no method available in BannerView class to shift position.

bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);